# Xcode build problems

Tags: build, clang, xcode4.3, symbols, invocation

I'm getting these feedbacks for two errors I keep getting when I try to "build" (which fails):
(this project built & ran fine before I upgraded my IOS device to 5.1 -- I can't even use the simulator either)

1st error:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in BTInclinometerViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

2nd error:
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What I don't understand is:
-- What does Xcode mean by the term "symbol";
-- How do I go about Identifying and then satisfying the missing symbol;
-- How do I "(use -v to see invocation)"

I'm using a MAC OSX 10.7.3 and Xcode version 4.3.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the Core Location framework in your project. Go to you Project, Build Phases, Link Binary with Library. Then add the framework.

If you have, make sure you include the right headers in your class.